# How to identify a line in a cursor?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Is a cursor internally numerated? Is there any way to identify the present line of a cursor while doing a **cursor FOR loop**?

I'm updating a table and I want the update to be made in the row that equals the present line of the cursor. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c
  is
  -- (...)
BEGIN
  FOR reg IN c
  LOOP
    UPDATE table
       SET column = 'abc'
     WHERE ROWNUM = -- current line of the cursor
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It would be better if you use the same `where` statement on the update that you use in the query. I can't see a situation that this would work properly in a data set. Because the line rows is not the same each time it runs

Comment: I can't use the same WHERE statement because the cursor is considering new "fields" that don't exist in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection types in oracle instead of a cursor.
More specifically, Index-by-tables or associative arrays are the ones you are looking for.

More details about how to use them is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#20023) and  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_collections.htm).

Comment: could you please give me a small example related to the code I posted?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE ROWNUM = ?` is never going to work (except for ? = 1).

The way ROWNUM works in Oracle is that it is only incremented when the row is actually selected. So it can never reach 2 before reaching 1 first (which it cannot because of WHERE ROWNUM = 2 for the "first" row).

The only useful condition is `ROWNUM < ?` (and that is not as useful as you might think, because it is applied before `ORDER BY`).

---

Even if it worked, without an `ORDER BY`, you'll run into extremely unpredictable results.

---

For the question you actually asked, you can use the `%ROWCOUNT` attribute of the cursor.

`c%ROWCOUNT` gives you the number of rows fetched so far.

Comment: so, to use a cursor FOR loop would never be a solution for this case?

Comment: Hard to say without more context. Don't you have primary key ids in that cursor that you can use to update? And do you actually need the cursor (as opposed to UPDATE WHERE)?

Comment: I'm using a cursor as I thought that it would be the best solution to fetch, save and update the data. The problem here is: I can't find a way to identify each row that the cursor is fetching so the UPDATE WHERE clause I'm using is updating only one line of the table with all the data that the loop is retrieving.